# How to check whether url used in IMAGE formula was correct and image is displayed?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a list of images I reference using their filenames:

```
=image("domainname.com/somepath/"&A2&".jpg")
```

where in A2 is a filename.

Unfortunately some of these images have .png extension.
I try to find a solution to check if file with jpg extension is correct and image is found. If not found I want to use

```
 =image("domainname.com/somepath/"&a2&".png")
```

For this cell.

IFNA and IFERROR formulas do not work.
I tried also to concatenate formulas:

```
=image("domainname.com/somepath/"&a2&".png")&image("domainname.com/somepath/"&a2&".jpg")
```

but I see that you can use & only for strings

There are thousands of images in different folders for reference and I cannot control their format.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One workaround I would suggest is to create and use a custom function to validate the image URL.

[**Custom Functions**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions#guidelines_for_custom_functions)

- Google Sheets offers hundreds of built-in functions like AVERAGE, SUM, and VLOOKUP. When these aren’t enough for your needs, you can use Google Apps Script to write custom functions — say, to convert meters to miles or fetch live content from the Internet — then use them in Google Sheets just like a built-in function.

**Sample Custom Function:**

```
/**
 * validate image
 *
 * @param {input} image url to validate.
 *
 * @customfunction
 */
function IMAGE_TRY(input) {
  
  try{
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(input);
      return 1;
  } catch(err) {
    
      return 0;
  }

}
```

- This custom function will take 1 image URL argument and verify if that URL is valid using the try-catch method. The function will return 1 when the URL is valid and 0 if not a valid URL

Note that the @customfunction tag is important in the function comment so that this custom function will appear as a suggested formula when you are typing in a cell.

---

Once you have created a custom function, you can use this to validate the URL and use the correct image URL using IF function.

**Sample:**

```
=IF(IMAGE_TRY("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_160x56dp.jpg"),image("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_160x56dp.jpg"), image("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_160x56dp.png"))
```

**Sample Output:**

[image]

---

---

(UPDATE)

**OPTIMIZED SOLUTION:**

**Sample Custom Function:**

```
/**
 * get image url with correct file extension.
 *
 * @param {input} image url string without extension.
 *
 * @customfunction
 */
function getURL(input) {
  
  try{
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(input+".jpg");
       return (input.concat(".jpg"));
  } catch(err) {
    
      return (input.concat(".png"));
  }

}
```

- This solution accepts an image URL without file extension and return an image URL with the valid file extension.

**Sheets Formula:**

```
=image(getURL("https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_160x56dp"))
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad that I could help

Comment: If it is of any additional value, here is an article that takes you through the same above logic, perhaps in more detail, but it is the same answer as Ron has already provided.  https://medium.com/@the.benhawy/how-to-use-google-spreadsheets-to-check-for-broken-links-1bb0b35c8525

Comment: Great answer! Welcome !

Comment: @KrzysztofDołęgowski, I added an optimized solution which will lessen the formula needed to get the correct image. Feel free to select which solution you prefer.